# Initialise issue jscrollpane & Ajax update panel in sharepoint 2010 visual webpart

Tags: ajax, jscrollpane, visual-web-developer-2010, jscrollbar

jscrollpane working OK, on onload of my visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 along with calendar, listview. But once clicked on the individual days, my code looks for the specific day events and renders in list view (data binding, with partial postbacks) which makes jscrollpane destroys. no luck with "Initialise"

found below links:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jscrollpane/kCewnCVaZMk

Thanks in advance.
DRS